# Reading POST Ajax array parameters in NanoHttpd

Tags: java, ajax, nanohttpd

I'm a NanoHttpd newbie. I'm shifting my Java EE servlet code into NanoHttpd for embedded usage. Please don't recommend other embedded servers like Jetty, I'd like to use NanoHttpd in particular.

My jQuery Javascript code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'',
    traditional: true,
    data: {
       'prm1':'val2',
       'prm2':'val2',
       'array1':['array1','array2','array3']
    },
    success:function(result){},
    error:function(xhr,err,stat){}
});
```

On a servlet getting parameters would look like this:

```
String serverval1 = request.getParameter("prm1"); //get single value
String serverval2 = request.getParameter("prm2"); //get single value  
String[] params = request.getParameterValues("array1"); //get array
```

On NanoHttpd I can get individual values via:

```
String serverval1 = ihttpsession.getParms().get("prm1"); //get single value
String serverval2 = ihttpsession.getParms().get("prm2"); //get single value 
String[] params = ???
```

How do I get array parameters in NanoHttpd?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after seeing a few more NanoHttpd sample codes, apparently there are many ways to get the request parameters

```
String serverval1 = ihttpsession.getParms().get("prm1"); //get single value
String serverval2 = ihttpsession.getParms().get("prm2"); //get single value

//get parameters as array (alternative method)
Map<String,List<String>>prms=decodeParameters(ihttpsession.getQueryParameterString());
String[] array = prms.get("array1").toArray(new String[prms.get("array1").size()]);
```

the later method can also be used on non array parameters but will obviously contain only one value in their respective `List<String>` object